# Where have I made a mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been trying the integral below, but cannot get the right answer and I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Let
$$I=\int_0^{1/2}\arcsin(\sqrt{x})dx$$
and make the substitution
$\sqrt{x}=\sin(u)$ so $dx=2\sin(u)\cos(u)du$.
Now,
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{\pi/4}2u\sin(u)\cos(u)du = \left[u\sin^2(u)\right]_0^{\pi/4}-\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin^2(u)du \\
&= \frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/4}(1-\cos(2u)) \, du \\
&= \frac{\pi}{8}-\left[\frac{u}{2}-\frac{\sin(2u)}{4}\right]_0^{\pi/4} = \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: That's the same answer [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arcsin(sqrt(x))+from+0+to+1%2F2&t=crmtb01) gets.

Comment: Hmmm. The answer book I checked it against said something different but my calculator also gave this answer, I presumed it was something I had typed in wrong

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: What does the answer book say?

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: It was just a problem I found on a website and the answer contained some fraction of $\pi$ as well, even though I can clearly see it cancelling. Annoyingly I can't find the site now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us see:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1/2}\arcsin\sqrt{x}\,dx&\stackrel{x\mapsto z^2}{=}&\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}2z\arcsin(z)\,dz\\&\stackrel{z\mapsto\sin\theta}{=}&\int_{0}^{\pi/4}2\theta\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta\\&\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\varphi/2}{=}&\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\varphi\sin\varphi\,d\varphi\\&=&\frac{1}{4}\left[\sin\varphi-\varphi\cos\varphi\right]_{0}^{\pi/2}=\frac{1}{4}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

---

Alternative method. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n$ we have
$$ \arcsin(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n+1} $$
for any $x\in(0,1)$ and
$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}\arcsin\sqrt{x}\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)8^n}\binom{2n}{n},$$
which equals $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}\,\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{5}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$, is a telescopic series in disguise.

Comment: Is This $F_1$ a geometric function?

Comment: @HenryLee: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html